# How to get files out of all subfolders and move them up to the first folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, file-recovery

I have around 3 TB of recovered data from a broken hard drive. The problem is all the files and folders are completely scrambled and placed into thousands of sub folders.

### Question

Is there a series of commands I can run in `cmd` that finds all files and move them up into the first folder and get rid of empty sub folders along the way?

If the found files can be sorted by file extension and placed into new folder for each extension that would be even better. I'm using a windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Batch Script Solution

You can set the parent folder that contains all the files within the structure you need to copy up to the parent folder as a variable. You can then use a [for /r](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) loop and some conditional [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic and **variable substitutions** to perform the copy, delete, and file extension folder creation operations as needed.

You can use some conditional logic to check if a file to be copied already exist in the destination folder and if so then [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) a subroutine and pass variable substitutions to it to append `_(dupe)` to that file name so it'll not overwrite existing files with the same file name.

To quickly remove the empty directories within the parent folder location you can run a [`Robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) command such as `Robocopy <dest> <dest> /S /MOVE` where the `destination` and `source` parameters are both the same and equal the full parent folder path.

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "Parent=C:\Momma"
SET "dupCnt=1"

FOR /R "%Parent%" %%C IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%Parent%\%%~XC" MD "%Parent%\%%~XC"
    IF NOT EXIST "%Parent%\%%~XC\%%~NXC" (
        XCOPY /Y /F "%%~C" "%Parent%\%%~XC\" && DEL /Q /F "%%~C"
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :Routine "%Parent%\%%~XC\%%~NXC" "%%~C" "%%~NC" "%%~XC"
        )
    )
Robocopy "%Parent%" "%Parent%" /S /MOVE
GOTO :EOF

:Routine
IF EXIST "%Parent%\%~4\%~3_(dupe%dupCnt%)%~4" (
    SET /A dupCnt=%dupCnt%+1
    CALL :Routine "%~1" "%~2" "%~3" "%~4"
) ELSE ( 
    IF EXIST "%~1" (
        ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%~2" "%Parent%\%~4\%~3_(dupe%dupCnt%)%~4" && DEL /Q /F "%~2"
        SET "dupCnt=1"
        )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Before and After Folder Structure Example

**Before**

```
C:\MOMMA
├───Adult-Child
│       Adult-Child.jpg
│       Adult-Child.txt
│       Adult-Child.zzz
│       Baby.txt
│
├───Baby
│       Adult-Child.txt
│       Baby.jpg
│       Baby.txt
│       Baby.zzz
│       Teen.txt
│
└───Teen
        Adult-Child.txt
        Baby.txt
        Teen.jpg
        Teen.txt
        Teen.zzz
```

**After**

```
C:\MOMMA
├───.jpg
│       Adult-Child.jpg
│       Baby.jpg
│       Teen.jpg
│
├───.txt
│       Adult-Child.txt
│       Adult-Child_(dupe1).txt
│       Adult-Child_(dupe2).txt
│       Baby.txt
│       Baby_(dupe1).txt
│       Baby_(dupe2).txt
│       Teen.txt
│       Teen_(dupe1).txt
│
└───.zzz
        Adult-Child.zzz
        Baby.zzz
        Teen.zzz
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)
- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [MD](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html)
- [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)
- [DEL](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [CALL](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- **Batch Substitutions (FOR /?)**

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > ```
- [SET](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

  > **Arithmetic expressions (SET /a)**
  >
  > Placing expressions in "quotes" is optional for simple arithmetic but
  >   required for any expression using logical operators.
  >
  > Any `SET /A` calculation that returns a fractional result will be
  >   rounded down to the nearest whole integer.
  >
  > The expression to be evaluated can include the following operators:
  >
  > `+   Add                set /a "_num=_num+5"`

Comment: outstanding answer

Comment: +1! outstanding answer and thanks for dealing with the "duplicate file names" problem.

Comment: Hey, if you run this batch file a second time, is it my imagination or does it CREATE duplicates?  (dupe1) (dupe2) etc.

Comment: @whiskeychief To ensure I understand, if the file name already exists, yes it will still move the file but with a new `_(dupe#)` in the file name. It is supposed to increment the number in "dupe" by one until it gets one that does not exist. Are you seeing something different? There are likely going to be issues with file names or paths with special characters such as `[` or `]` too since it's batch. I'd likely redo this whole thing in PowerShell if I had to actually. Let me know what you are seeing specifically do I can test if when you get a chance.

Comment: If you want to have the source overwritten without dupe# incremented, then the logic would need to be changed to ensure the last copied file overwrites the existing file. Based on what the OP asked for in this question though, that is correct that it will create the dupe1, dupe2, and so on and not overwrite an existing file. To reiterate though, there may be special file name issues with this batch logic and I'd likely redo this entire thing in PowerShell rather than batch if I needed it to do something different. Adjusting this batch logic is trivial though otherwise really.

Comment: Yes you’re quite correct— it doesn’t create a duplicate file but it may add “dupe1” to all your files on second run.  Still this is a great batch file as is!   I just wish the directories it creates didn’t start with periods— those are often treated as “hidden” folders by Windows.

Comment: Answered my own question: it looks like you can get rid of leading periods by following with the following (Powershell 3 or higher:) `Dir -directory | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ".","" }`

Comment: ^ My comment is incorrect.   The following can be used to remove the periods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090156/replace-with-in-file-name/43090430#43090430

Comment: Nice! I use PowerShell more often now too by the way. I believe there is also a `-Hidden` parameter with `Get-ChildItem` I've used that that purpose too!

Answer (score 1):

[FreeCommander XE](https://freecommander.com/en/summary/) is a free utility (Windows Explorer alternative) that has a "flat view" functionality to see all files within the directory and all subdirectories.

It also has quite powerful selection/search options, so you can easily select files based on extension and move to a directory of your choice. Of course, it is manual work, but you keep control over what you are doing.

Overall a great tool, which has *saved my life* quite a few times when working with tons of files.

Answer (score 0):

From [How to Copy Files from Multiple Sub-Folders to a Single Folder?](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/move-copy-files-multiple-sub-folders-single-folder/)

Open a Command Prompt ('cmd.exe') window. Use the following commands:

```
cd /d "d:\vacation snaps\2016"

for /r %d in (*) do copy "%d" "d:\all snaps"
```

In the above **example**, the command recursively copies all files in the 'vacation snaps\2016' folder to the 'All Snaps' folder.

Alternately, use Windows Search. See [How to Copy Files from Multiple Sub-Folders to a Single Folder?](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/move-copy-files-multiple-sub-folders-single-folder/)

Comment: What happens when the above script encounters identical filenames?

Answer (score 0):

Install the free utility 'Everything' from http://voidtools.com/

This quickly indexes every file on your HDD. Open an 'everything' window and look for all files by typing `'*.*'` or `'driveletter:/folder/*.*`

Once this has all the files in the list, select all, then right click and select copy.

Paste into your folder, paying attention to the windows 10 dialogue box that may appear when it tries to paste a duplicate filename. It will give you the option to rename all, placing a number at the end of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I did it the hard way unfortunately. And whilst waiting for it to finish my way, I discovered this far better solution. DOH!

I opened a File Explorer window and searched: *.* kind:-folder

That gave me a list of all the files sans the folders. I then did a Ctrl-A to select all the files which I then cut and pasted where I needed them to be.

Script solution however far superior. Kudos!